# Segmentation fault error in tail recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, tail-recursion, c89

I am writing a function in C that converts a number to a different base such as octal, binary, hexadecimal, etc. We are required to write it recursively and the function must return a char *. However, I am getting a segmentation fault error on this snip pend of code. I am also not sure if the conversion is working properly because I cannot get past this error. I am brand new to C so I apologize if there is anything I am obviously missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *convertToBaseOut(short int num, int base);

int main()
{
    printf("%s", convertToBaseOut(256, 8));
    return 0;
}

char *convertToBaseOut(short int num, int base) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return '0';
    }
    return convertToBaseOut(num/base, base) + (num % base);
}
```

Segmentation fault

...Program finished with exit code 139

Comment: `return '0'` is returning a `char`, not `char*`. You should be getting a compiler warning about that.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect this to work. It looks like you're trying to do string concatenation with `+`, but that's not how you do it in C.

Comment: `return convertToBaseOut(num/base, base) + (num % base);` is taking a pointer, adding an offset to it, and then returning the adjusted pointer. In other words, it doesn't do anything at all like what you want it to do.

Comment: In C, you use the `strcat()` function to concatenate strings. But you never allocate any strings in your code.

Comment: This looks like you took a Python program and simply converted it to C syntax without understanding the differences between the two languages, especially regarding how they work with strings.

Comment: Hint: when the function reaches the base case, it should `malloc` memory for the string, and then each level of recursion needs to append its digit to the string. Each level of recursion, including the base case, should return the pointer that `malloc` returned.

Comment: Thank you @user3386109 I will take a look into how to do that :D

Comment: @Fragile Sounds good. You need to know three things about C: 1) how pointers work 2) how memory management works 3) how strings work. If you are coming from a Python background, this can be confusing because Python A) doesn't have pointers B) hides memory management C) has a totally different concept of a string. So it might help to have a conversation with a more experienced programmer to get an overview of pointers, memory management, and strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C you can't use + to concatenate strings.

Here you have simple recursive function:

```
size_t tostring(char *str, unsigned num, unsigned base)
{
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    size_t pos;
    if(!num)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        pos = tostring(str, num / base, base);
        str[pos++] = digits[num % base];
        str[pos] = 0;
    }
    return pos;
}

int main()
{

    char str[20];
    printf("%u\n" , tostring(str,0xabcd, 2));
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

It reruens length of the string as well.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to do this without changing the return type from char * because I need it to return that type.